# SWRevealViewController: notice the selected TableViewCell

Tags: ios, objective-c, swrevealviewcontroller

Hi I'm using `SWRevealViewController` combined with Storyboard. My main problem is, the selected view `tableViewCell` is not highlighted. If I reopen the `sideBar` it´s normal again. Is there any way to "save" this? I'm not very familiar with iOS development. I need to delegate?? I think the problem is the `setFrontViewPosition`? I need to `pushFrontViewController`?

I use this code from a tutorial:

```
-(void) prepareForSegue: (UIStoryboardSegue *) segue sender: (id) sender
{

    SWRevealViewController *revealController = [self revealViewController];
   if ( [segue isKindOfClass: [SWRevealViewControllerSegue class]] ) {
        SWRevealViewControllerSegue *swSegue = (SWRevealViewControllerSegue*) segue;

        swSegue.performBlock = ^(SWRevealViewControllerSegue* rvc_segue, UIViewController* svc, UIViewController* dvc) {

            UINavigationController* navController = (UINavigationController*)self.revealViewController.frontViewController;
            [navController setViewControllers: @[dvc] animated: NO ];
            [self.revealViewController setFrontViewPosition: FrontViewPositionLeft animated: YES];

        };

    }
   else {
      [revealController revealToggleAnimated:YES];
   }

}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of [Highlight active link in SWRevealViewController](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23698043/highlight-active-link-in-swrevealviewcontroller)